# Handcoded var exists.. on load auto trigger to specific value

Tags: jquery

Hi,

if `a1` is there... load `test1.html.. if a2 is there.. load test2.html.`

Getting JS error.. not sure how to declare variable inside option.

Please help me to assist to fix this issue. Thanks in advance.

**JS:**

```
var defaultVal = 'a1';
$('#testElement option[id=defaultVal]').attr('selected', 'selected');

$('#testElement').trigger('change');
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suppose you mean to do something like this:

```
var defaultVal = 'a1';
$('#testElement option[id='+defaultVal+']').attr('selected', 'selected');
```

So you can control `defaultVal` dynamically.